# Django, некорректно выводится queryset в шаблон

Tags: python, django

Пытаюсь выводить в шаблон данные. Queryset формируется за текущую неделю, данные - тренировки на определенную дату. В моем случае присутствует 4 объекта (по 1 тренировке в пн, чт, сб, воск). Формирую словарь {дата: объект из базы} и пытаюсь вывести в шаблон.
Проблема в том, что данные выводятся некорректно, а именно: почему-то тренировки выводятся просто чередуясь с пустым днём (тренировка, пустой день, тренировка...).

Модель:

```
class Workout(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date = models.DateField()
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='workouts'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Вьюшка формирования данных:

```
def make_week_content(request, date, week_day, next, prev):
    view_allow = request.user
    week = date.strftime("%V")
    start_date = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=week_day)
    dates = [(start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=i)).date() for i in
             range(7)]
    schedule = {}
    for dt in dates:
        schedule[dt] = Workout.objects.filter(
            date__week=week,
            date__week_day=dt.weekday(),
            author__username=view_allow)

    context = {
        'schedule': schedule,
        'dates': dates,
        'next': next,
        'prev': prev
    }
    return render(request, 'workouts/workout_week.html', context)
```

Вьюшка вывода данных:

```
@login_required
def workout_week(request):
    date = datetime.datetime.today()
    week_day = datetime.datetime.now().isocalendar()[2] - 1
    return make_week_content(request, date, week_day, True, True)
```

Шаблон:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
  <div style="width: 100%;">
    {% for key, value in schedule.items %}
      <div style="float: left; width: 13.6%; margin-left: 5px;">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
              {{ key|date:"d M Y" }} <br> {{ key|date:"l" }}
            </div>
          {% if value %}
              {% for workout in value %}
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h6 class="card-title">{{ workout.title }}</h6>
                  <p class="card-text">{{ workout.text }}</p>
                  <a href="{% url 'workouts:workout_detail' workout.pk %}"
                  class="btn btn-primary">Подробно</a>
                </div>
              {% endfor %}
          {% else %}
            <div class="card-body">
              <h6 class="card-title">Сегодня отдых</h6>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Добавить треню?</a>
            </div>
          {% endif %}
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

Я тестово вывожу кверисет в шаблон и вижу, что он не верен. Объекты просто чередуются, а нужно, чтобы данными заполнились вт, чт, сб, воск, в остальные дни вывод текста: "тренировки нет".
Помогите разобраться пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос.

```
for dt in dates:
    schedule[dt] = Workout.objects.filter(
        date__week=week,
        date__week_day=(dt.isoweekday() % 7) + 1,
        author__username=view_allow)
```